# how to overwrite a builtin method of javascript native objects

Tags: javascript, overriding, prototype-programming, built-in

Lets say we have alert method of window object. I would like to enhance it with nice alertbox.

Also I want to save the existing alert method so that we can switch back once our application is over.

Something like this, but its throwing error in firefox console.

```
window.prototype.alert = function(){

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can;

```
var base = window.alert;
window.alert = function(message) {
    document.getElementById("myalertwidget").innerHTML = message;
    return base.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: `base.apply(this, arguments)` just correctly calls the *original* `alert()` should you wish to do so

Answer (score 5):

There is no `window.prototype` object. `window` is a global object of javascript context and it is not created from the prototype.

However, what you want to do is achievable with the following code:

```
window.old_alert = window.alert;  
window.alert = function(txt) {
      // do what you need
      this.old_alert(txt);
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is `Window.prototype`.