# How to format numbers in javascript to two decimal digits?

Tags: javascript

I need to format numbers to two decimal digits in javascript. In order to do this I am using toFixed method which is working properly.

But in cases, where numbers don't have any decimal digits, it should not show decimal point

e.g. 10.00 should be 10 only and not 10.00.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.toFixed()` converts the result to **String**,
so **you need to convert it back to Number:**

```
parseFloat( num.toFixed(2) )
```

or by simply using the *Unary `+`*

```
+num.toFixed(2)
```

**both will give the following**:

```
//   15.00   --->   15
//   15.20   --->   15.2
```

If you only want to get rid of the `.00` case, than you can go for String manipulation using `.replace()`

```
num.toFixed(2).replace('.00', '');
```

**Note**: the above will convert your `Number` to `String`.

Comment: `+(num.toFixed(2))` is less to type. ;-)

Comment: But this doesn't do exactly what was asked, 10 -> 10, 10.111 -> 10.11 but 10.1 -> 10.1 and I would have expected 10.10 if the format is to be 2 dp except for whole numbers? I would have thought something like this `num.toFixed(2).split('.00', 1)`

Comment: @Xotic750—agree, but the OP has chosen it. Don't you mean `num.toFixed(2).split('.00')[0]`? There's also `num.toFixed(2).replace('.00','')`.

Comment: @RobG They would also work, here is a [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/kjphefaL/) using my suggestion. [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) using the `limit` argument.

Comment: @Xotic750— *split* returns an array, so you're relying on *toString* when it's assigned via *textContent*. It works, but I think explicitly selecting the member is better. And there will only be one `.00` anyway.

Comment: @RobG True, I was relying on `toString` to do the conversion, so yes being explicit would be better. Need more coffee. :)

Comment: **NOTE:** using `num.toFixed(2).replace('.00', '');` directly is very risky.
It will turn 1.001234 to 11234

Comment: @Wale nope. Paste in console: `(1.001234).toFixed(2).replace('.00', '')` - it returns `"1"`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Note that in the answer above, ```num``` was converted to string using ```parseFloat(num``` or unary operator `+num`

Comment: @Wale No. In the above answer the is no prior conversion to anything (`num =`). Those are three separate examples on their own where the usage should look i.e:  `const numConverted = (num).toFixed(2).replace('.00', '');`. Please create a jsfiddle.net with the exact issue you're referencing in your comment.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to make this change global(if you need, of course), try this:

```
var num1 = 10.1;
var num2 = 10;

var tofixed = Number.prototype.toFixed;

Number.prototype.toFixed = function(precision)
{
    var num = this.valueOf();

    if (num % 1 === 0)
    {
        num = Number(num + ".0");
    }

    return tofixed.call(num, precision);
}

console.log(num1.toFixed(2));
console.log(num2.toFixed(2));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x14zf1d2/). This is a mix of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8909557/1267304) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3885817/1267304) post.